# Dell tower and server 2012(upgrade), how to store and migrate data while doing it

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am looking to buy a new tower server from Dell. And put Server 2012 into it. Then I want to migrate all the data into the new server and get rid of old one. Can you please the exact steps for how to do this? Other than that, what should I be taking care of while doing this.

Looking forward to your explained reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you need to take:

> 1) Call Dell and buy a server.  Any server will do.
>
> 2) Ask Dell to put Server 2012 on your new server, they will install
>   it for free.
>
> 3) Unbox your new server and connect it to your network.
>
> 4) Open file explorer and drag and drop the folder with all your data
>   to the new Dell.
>
> 5) Set the admin password and create an account for yourself.
>
> 6) Put your old server for sale on Ebay.